# Right justify animated font awesome icon within bootstrap list group

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, bootstrap-4

I am trying to display a list of statuses with the text on the left and results on the right.  I am using the font awesome heart animation to show a pulsing heart.  I want the heart to be right justified but can't seem to get it to be right justified:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6 server-dashboard-list">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between" >
                Database Up
                <span class="database-up text-colour-red" ><i class="fa fa-heart faa-pulse animated fa-1-5-font-size"></i></span>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">
                Active Database Connections
                <span class="badge badge-pill active-database-connections"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The badge is right justified but the heart isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi im not entirely sure if this is what you wanted but hopefully it helps...

but if you were to give the span that you have the heart in a new class and in your css under that class you can put `float: right;`. it should move it to the right.

If you need more help holla my way.

Comment: I tried that and it still didn't float.  I then realised I needed to set the width of ul to 100% and that fixed it. Thank you.  I then realised I could use the class pull-right instead of style=float:right.